# Best strategy to distribute workload to workers

Tags: java, multithreading, data-processing

I have big amount of data, which I have to process and I want to use multithreaded approach.
Let's say I have 1_000_000 objects, which have to be processed and I have thread pool of size 4 (8, 16).

What is the best strategy to distribute this workload? I can think of 2 things:

1. Each object = 1 task for executor service. Seems to be the worst decision, even comparing to processing everything in 1 thread.
2. Divide the total number of object into number of workers. E.g. in case of 4 workers, each will get 250k objects to process. This is very straightforward and it seems to me that there can be some other options.

Please share your thought and other approaches (probably something with FJP can be more efficient)

Comment: Start with a pool of "works", each work in turn asks for a piece of data to be processed (from a queue), as each piece is processed, it could be placed in a "completed" queue or where ever and then the process repeats till there are no more pieces in the queue

Comment: @MadProgrammer If the data is reasonably homogenous in terms of processing demand (as hinted by OP), it's better to avoid the additional synchronization of a shared queue.

Comment: Is the workload distributed on a single machine or across many hosts? In case you have 1 host only, you can simply use an `ExecutorService` with a number of worker threads equal to your processor's core count.

Answer (score 0):

You considered corner cases: 1 task contains 1 object and 1 task contains 250k objects. Very likely, the best batch size is somewhere in between. Try these configurations and write down the times spend. Try also 8, 64, 500, 4k and 32k objects. Then look at the best time. If, for example, the best time is for 500, then also try 125, 250, 1k and 2k, and so on. This is similar to binary search, but in logarithmic scale.